# the number of rows in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that has only one column. I want to extract the number of rows.
When I run the the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

I get the following output:

```
[65422771 rows x 1 columns]
```

But when I run the code below:

```
file = open("data.csv")
numline = len(file.readlines())
print (numline)
```

I get the following output:

```
130845543
```

What is the correct number of rows in my csv file? What is the difference between the two outputs?

Comment: What does `df.shape[0]` return?

Comment: df.shape[0] returns 65422771

Comment: Given that for `read_csv` the parameter `skip_blank_lines` is `TRUE` by default I'm guessing you have many blank lines in the CSV file, per @Giovannirison's answer below.  An answer to this is going to need a sample of what is in the CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have an empty line after each entry? because the `readlines` count is exactly double wrt pandas df rows.
So pandas is skipping empty lines while `readlines` count them

in order to check the number of empty lines try:

```
import sys
import csv

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
   
data= open ('data.csv')
for line in csv.reader(data): 
    if not line: 
        empty_lines += 1 
        continue
    print line
```

Comment: There are empty rows but not after each entry.

Comment: @BNoor try to run the code above to check the number of empty lines in your csv

Comment: _csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)

Comment: @BNoor updated, but that error means that your csv is badly formatted